# How can I install Skype on Freya?

Tags: release-freya, skype

I am newbie to Freya and I need to install Skype. I tried to download it from the Skype website but there is no support for Freya. There's only an Ubuntu version `.deb`. Now I don't know how to install it.

Comment: A quick Google search found a number of sites showing how to do this.

Comment: ofcourse many tuts are there. but those are all new. even me too wrote about it. http://www.kvcodes.com/2015/11/install-skype-and-teamviewer-on-freya/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Removing previous version**(If you have)

```
sudo apt-get remove skype skype-bin:i386 skype:i386
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
```

Clear the old Skype folder before installing latest version.

```
rm -rf ~/.Skype
```

**Preparing to Installing Skype**:

Users of 64-bit  should enable MultiArch if it isn't already enabled by running the command:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Update repositories and "updates" list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now,

Open *Software& Update* --> *Other software* tab then 
enable *Canonical Partner repository*.

[image: Imgur]

Then close --> reload

**Install skype**

Now open terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Reference [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype)